# How to overwrite lock for editing ?

Tags: vba

I have an `xlsx` file on a shared drive .  The problem is that sometimes I need to modify it, but find out that somebody else is using it, and it is 'locked for editing' . How can I get rid of this `locked for editing` thing ?

PS : I do not want to set up a password on it .

Comment: So you want to edit it at the same time as the other person? What if they then want to save their changes?

Comment: Nobody will edit it except for me. People just open it and use as it is without editing or saving anything .

Comment: You can't. You need the other user to close out of the file.  How is this question programming-related?

Comment: You can only programmatically know that it's being used. Then you'll need to notify the user somehow

Comment: You can "suggest" the user to open it read-only: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/prompt-to-open-a-file-as-read-only-HP005186091.aspx. But honestly, just use a "password to edit" rule on the file level: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/password-protect-a-workbook-HA102809707.aspx. Or use Google Docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know the presence of a lock by the following code. There is something called `FreeFile()` which you'll need to use to trap some error codes

Basically this is what you do...

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim Check as Integer, ErrorNumber as Integer
Check = FreeFile()

Open FileNameString For Input Lock ReadAs #Check
Close Check
ErrorNumber = Err
```

Now if there is no Error, ErrorNumber would say 0, if it's open, ErrorNumber would say 70

More details on this in the MS Knowledge Base article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291295

Comment: How does this *unlock* an xlsx file?

Comment: It shows the presence of a lock as mentioned. That is not very straightforward in VBA but can be done as shown. Unlocking is not possible.